# Eclipse Android App using JSoup, always ending within the Catch

Tags: android, eclipse, jsoup

I have some code that uses JSoup and connects to a website successfully in JAVA.

I am trying to duplicate the exact same thing (as a learning experience) on  the Android.

I am using Eclipse.

Within my activity_main.xml I have 3 buttons and a text field.

I do not have any errors within my JAVA code and have confirmed it still works within JAVA (running in Netbeans)

I have my JSoup jar within the libs folder ~ that was an issue that took  a little while to find.

I have placed some editText.setText(“Here”); to see where the code gets.

I have a message immediately below my doc = JSoup.connect(“http://www.Google.com”).get();

I never get that message.

Likewise I have the same message within my catch routine – I am always getting into the catch routine, meaning I have a problem.

I have tried this two ways – with the android emulator and with my phone attached through the USB cable. I get the same result – the “app” runs fine but displays the message found within the catch{}.

I am at a loss since the exact code works fine within Netbeans / regular JAVA.

Here is my code:

```
package com.example.duckriver;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;
import org.jsoup.helper.Validate;


public class MainActivity extends Activity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)  {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}

int counter;
Button Button1;
Button SummaryStats;
TextView display;
TextView editText;

String dataread = null;
String high = "High:";
String low = "Low:";
String filename = null;
int index = 0;
int startindex = 0;
int lastindex = 0;
int length = 0;
char[] CharArray = new char[1000];



@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)  
{
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    counter = 0;
    Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    SummaryStats = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSummaryStats);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMainDisplay);

    editText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);



    Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) 
{
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

            //counter++;


            Document doc;
            try{
                doc=Jsoup.connect("http://www.Google.com").get();
                editText.setText("Here");


        //get Title
                //String title = doc.title();
                //System.out.println("Title: "+title);

                //dataread = doc.body().text(); // "An example link"


                Element link = null;

            }//end try
            catch(Exception ex){
                ex.printStackTrace();
                editText.setText("Error");
                //((TextView)findViewById(R.id.tv)).setText("Error");
        }// end catch




        }
    });

    SummaryStats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter = counter*counter;


        }
    });

    return true;
}

}
```

I am at a loss. Help?

Thanks.

Comment: What version of Android are you testing on? What exception do you get?

Comment: Definitely, your API level >= 11, and hence you might need to fix [NetworkOnMainThreadException](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/NetworkOnMainThreadException.html)

Comment: Have you forgot to put this in your manifest? <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

Comment: Regarding the version of Android - I am unsure, it will be whatever was set when I started Eclipse. I fired it up and started on some tutorials.

Comment: Likewise, regarding the manifest - I am unclear on that also and API level. Am I correct to take from these comments that the issue may be an Eclipse deal and not my code?

Answer (score 1):

You need download document with Asyncronous task or Android will throw exception. Try this:

```
@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu)  
{
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);

    counter = 0;
    Button1 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);
    SummaryStats = (Button) findViewById(R.id.buttonSummaryStats);
    display = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvMainDisplay);

    editText = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.editText);



    Button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()  {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
           downloadDocTask task = new downloadDocTask();
           task.execute("www.google.com");
         }
    });

    SummaryStats.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            counter = counter*counter;


        }
    });

    return true;
}


    private class downloadDocTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Document>{
        String urldisplay;
        @Override
        protected Document doInBackground(String... urls) {
            urldisplay = urls[0];
            Document doc = null;
            try {
                doc = Jsoup.connect(urldisplay).timeout(10*1000).get();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return doc;
            }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Document result) {
            if(result != null){
                Log.i(TAG, "downloadDocTask.onPostExcecute Document Download complete");
                buildHtml(result);
            }
            else{
                Log.i(TAG, "downloadDocTask.onPostExcecute Document == null");
            }
        }

    }


public void buildHtml(Document doc){
   // Parse document here
   String title = doc.title();
}
```